# How to delete a row in cassandra if a column is null

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there a way to delete multiple rows from `Cassandra CF` using `CQL query` without using key in the filter condition?

Something like `DELETE FROM [ColumnFamily] WHERE [NonKeyColumnName] = [Value]`
OR
`DELETE FROM [ColumnFamily] WHERE [NonKeyColumnName] IS NULL` ?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that. Deletion operation can be done on **rowkey** only.

And if the column is null, then you don't have to worry. The GC will remove that while compacting.